# Modelling data from a single timestamp to a record with valid_from/valid_to timestamps when there is a change

Tags: sql, database, presto, trino

Here is **table1** with some example data:

| id | date_column | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/03/2021 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 07/03/2021 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 08/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 09/03/2021 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 05/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 09/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |

I want to transform it into the following format:

| id | valid_from | valid_to | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/03/2021 | 08/03/2021 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 08/03/2021 | 09/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 09/03/2021 | 01/01/2100 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 05/03/2021 | 01/01/2100 | 1 | 1 |

So a new row in the desired format is created every time there is a new value in **col1** or **col2**.

The **valid_from** is the the earliest value in **date_column** for this unique values in col1 and col2, while the the **valid_to** is the earliest value in **date_column** when any of these values have changed.

I was able to to achieve this transformation with the following SQL (Presto specific):

```sql
WITH base AS (
SELECT
*
FROM (
  VALUES
    (1, date('2021-03-06'), NULL, 1),
    (1, date('2021-03-07'), NULL, 1),
    (1, date('2021-03-08'), 1, 1),
    (1, date('2021-03-09'), 1, 2),
    (2, date('2021-03-05'), 1, 1),
    (2, date('2021-03-09'), 1, 1)
) AS t (id, date_column, col1, col2)
)

, base2 AS (
SELECT
  id
, date_column
, col1
, col2
, array_join(array[cast(col1 AS VARCHAR),
                   cast(col2 AS VARCHAR)], '','null') AS col_dedup
FROM
  base
)

, base3 AS (
SELECT
  id
, date_column
, col1
, col2

, coalesce(
    lag(col_dedup) OVER (PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY date_column) = col_dedup, 
    false
) AS same_as_previous

from base2
)

SELECT
  id
, date_column                                                                          AS valid_from
, lead(date_column, 1, date('2100-01-01')) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_column) AS valid_to
, col1
, col2
FROM
  base3
WHERE
  same_as_previous = false
ORDER BY
  id
, date_column ASC
```

The difficulty is when you have 100 columns, all of these 100 columns must appear in the `array_join`.

Now the actual question - is there a better way of doing the above transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem . . . but actually a simple version.  You want the first row of each grouping.  Then `lead()` to get the end date:

```
select id, col1, col2, datecol as valid_from,
       lead(datecol, 1, '2100-01-01') over (partition by id order by datecol) as valid_to
from (select t1.*,
             lag(datecol) over (partition by id order by datecol) as prev_datecol,
             lag(datecol) over (partition by id, col1, col2 order by datecol1) as prev_datecol_12
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where prev_datecol_12 is null or 
      (prev_datecol <> prev_datecol_12);
```

Note that this method does not require aggregation, which is typically faster.

More importantly, this handles groups where the values *return* to a previous set of values.  Your method does not do that.  I am guessing that this is what you really want for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. You will still be partitioning by the id and all the columns. So if you have 100 columns to check, you will need to partition by 100 columns. Is there a way to avoid this? Or at least insert these columns into the partition dynamically, so there would be no need to manually specify 100 columns in the partition?

Comment: @NickScriabin. . . That part is tricky.  However, you can just cut and paste the column names into a query (which is pretty simple).  You could attempt to use some sort of JSON, but that gets quite complicated because you need to filter out certain columns.  Note:  You can get all the columns in a table using `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: Is it possible to insert the columns from information_schema.columns directly into the `PARTITION BY` clause? Or it will still be a copy-paste job?

Comment: @NickScriabin . . . Unless you use dynamic SQL (constructing SQL as a string), it is a cut-and-paste job.